# Adobe AIR license agreement showing instead of installed AIR applications

Tags: air, licensing

I have a user who is experiencing the following issue - when he tries to run an AIR application, the license agreement shows (accept/decline), and then nothing (the app doesn't launch when you click accept).

This happens for all his AIR applications (not just the one we developed), he's tried uninstalling and reinstalling both AIR and the app. He's using windows 7

this is what shows when he launches an AIR App:

[image]

http://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/2-4001609-88833/license.png

Any clue as to how to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing AIR is failing to install because of lacking permissions, and gets confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the User:

"Finally got it to work by going into my c:\users\my-user\Appdata\Roaming\Adobe\AIR directory and renaming my old eulaAccepted file to eulaAccepted-old"

Answer (score 1):

Adobe site solution: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4170695.

It has to do with a bad/corrupted eulaAccepted file. I corrected my problem by deleting the eulaAccepted file and then rerunning the program; which then created a good eulaAccepted file.